# Android tag requires a 'drawable' attribute Error

Tags: android

in Android studio i get this error:

```
<item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
```

but i dont have this error on Intellij, my Style is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#000000" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="#ededed" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

and i use that on widget background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to:

[Selector documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

You need to define a drawable as part of a selector:

> **Item**
>
> Defines a drawable to place in the layer drawable, in a
>   position defined by its attributes. Must be a child of a **selector**
>   element. Accepts child **bitmap** elements. attributes:
>
> android:drawable Drawable resource. Required. Reference to a drawable
>   resource.

black_bg.xml (in drawable folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <solid android:color="#0000"/>

  </shape>
```

grey_bg.xml (in drawable folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <solid android:color="#ededed"/>

    </shape>
```

selector.xml (also in drawables folder)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/black_bg" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/grey_bg" />
</selector>
```